# Indicating the differential on a graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

i would like to indicate on a graph the error in estimating f(x) using a linearization to the graph of f. To indicate the distance between points A and B, I would like a thin vertical line, with arrowheads at both ends, drawn between them. Also, I need to have `$\delta y$` in scriptstyle (or footnotesize) to be typeset in the middle of this vertical line, or, if there is not enough space, to the right of the vertical line, vertically centered.  I saw in a user's code the following command which should be useful.

```
\draw[|<->|] ((B)!3mm!90:(A)$)
  --node[fill=white,sloped]
  {$\delta y$} ($(A)!3mm!-90:(B)$);
```

### Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=6in,axis equal image,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-3,xmax=10,
    domain=-10:10, samples=501,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-2.5,ymax=,
    restrict y to domain=-2.5:5,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    extra x ticks={2},
    extra x tick labels={$x_{\circ}$},
    yticklabel style={anchor=west},
    yticklabel shift=-4pt,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[samples=251,latex-latex,domain=-1:5, thin] {(40/(10 * ln(10))) * x - 50/(10 * ln(10)) + 1};
\addplot[samples=501,domain=-0.333:9,blue] {(1/ln(10)) * ln(40*x - 40)}
node[pos=0.8, anchor=north, font=\footnotesize] {$y=\log(40x - 40)$};
\addplot [dashed, latex-latex, samples=251,domain=-5:5] (1,x) node[pos=0.1, anchor=south, font=\footnotesize, sloped] {$x=1$};
\draw [fill] (1.25,1) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill] (2,2.30288) circle [radius=1.5pt] node[above left] {$B$};
\draw [fill] (2,1.60206) circle [radius=1.5pt] node[below right] {$A$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a slight variation of the command you provided:

```
\draw[|<->|,red] ($(2,2.30288)!3mm!90:(2,1.60206)$) -- ($(2,1.60206)!3mm!-90:(2,2.30288)$)
                node[midway, right] {$\delta y$};
```

which yields:

[image]

### Notes:

- As you had hard coded the coordinates for `(A)` and `(B)`, I inserted those into the above `\draw`.
- I also find it easier to place the `node` after the drawing, but that is just a personal preference.
- I eliminated the `fill=white`, otherwise part of the graph is obscured.
- I also eliminated the settings of the min and max values for `x` and `y` to improve the image provided here.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=6in,axis equal image,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    %xmin=-3,xmax=10,
    domain=-10:10, samples=501,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    %ymin=-2.5,%ymax=,
    restrict y to domain=-2.5:5,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    extra x ticks={2},
    extra x tick labels={$x_{\circ}$},
    yticklabel style={anchor=west},
    yticklabel shift=-4pt,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[samples=251,latex-latex,domain=-1:5, thin] {(40/(10 * ln(10))) * x - 50/(10 * ln(10)) + 1};
\addplot[samples=501,domain=-0.333:9,blue, thick] {(1/ln(10)) * ln(40*x - 40)}
node[pos=0.8, anchor=north, font=\footnotesize] {$y=\log(40x - 40)$};
\addplot [dashed, latex-latex, samples=251,domain=-5:5] (1,x) node[pos=0.1, anchor=south, font=\footnotesize, sloped] {$x=1$};
\draw [fill] (1.25,1) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill] (2,2.30288) circle [radius=1.5pt] node[above left] {$B$};
\draw [fill] (2,1.60206) circle [radius=1.5pt] node[below right] {$A$};

\draw[|<->|,red] ($(2,2.30288)!3mm!90:(2,1.60206)$) -- ($(2,1.60206)!3mm!-90:(2,2.30288)$)
    node[midway, right] {$\delta y$};
 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks nice!  I made one modification to your code - I put the pink vertical line directly between points A and B by declaring "0mm" instead of "3mm." (I was thinking that the `fill=white` optional command would obscure part of the graph, but since I didn't graph it, I wasn't sure. Having $\delta y$ to the right is appropriate.)

Comment: I decided that I don't want the points A and B labeled on the graph. I used the commands `(2,1.60206)coordinate(A)` and
`(2,2.30288)coordinate(B)` to declare these points in the code so that TikZ can use them to draw the pink vertical line between points A and B. Now, the graph looks very nice!